# Not sure how to get this working with respect a SQL query

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables named table1 and table2:

```
Table1
 id           date               email            cId
  1    2013-08-28 12:21:39     t@gmail.com       12345
  2    2013-07-27 10:15:18     k@gmail.com       12345
  3    2018-02-13 09:41:43     a@gmail.com       12345
  4    2018-02-02 10:14:42     n@gmail.com       45678
  5    2017-11-16 10:16:51     l@gmail.com       45678

Table2
 id           status
12345           1     
45678           1
56789           0
```

When I execute a query I am expecting to get row from table1 which has max date.

```
select c.id 'table 2 Id'
     , DATE_FORMAT(Max(u.date),'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') 'Date'
     , u.email 'User' 
  from table2 c
  LEFT 
  JOIN table1 u 
    ON u.cId = c.id 
 where c.status = 1 
 group 
    by c.id 
 order 
    by c.id;
```

How ever what I see is kind of confusing.

```
 table 2 Id           Date               USER       
  12345        2018-02-13 09:41:43     t@gmail.com
```

I am expecting the output to be

```
 table 2 Id           Date               USER       
 12345        2018-02-13 09:41:43     a@gmail.com
```

Because the max date that is selected is not same of the user t@gmail.com but of a@gmail.com

Any suggestions on where has it gone wrong and how can I tweak it to get correct result?

Comment: select * from table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on t1.cId = t2.id
where date = (select max(date) from table1)

Comment: `table2 c` and `table1 u` is it really that hard to use normal names? :)

Comment: @AnkushRathi a subquery inside a where clause for one given field is sub-optimal...

Comment: Thanks Strawberry, for helping me format it better. Apology this was my first query, will try to put it in better way going forward. Also @Michal, I know :) I wanted to ask the query with a example to understand where i was going wrong, in urgency I wrote names that first came in my mind.

Comment: Can someone else pour some more light on this please? tried few sub query options but none have been fruitful to give me the result i am looking for ;(

Comment: `GROUP BY` **is not** the tool for your need.

Comment: *"When I execute a query I am expecting to get row from table1 which has max date."* -- `GROUP BY` does not return rows from the table. It **generates** one row from each group of data. Each value in the generated row is computed independent of the other values.

Comment: Search for similar questions tagged with [tag:greatest-n-per-group].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you use a grouping function (i.e. max, sum, count, etc.) you must specify only segregating columns in the SELECT clause.
In your case, there are several emails for one given id, much like the date field.
You can't just specify

```
SELECT id, max(date), email ...
```

it wouldn't make sense, because you need to specify a grouping function for the mail.

What you're really interested in, is "the email that corresponds to the row whose date is max(date) for a given id".

This must be done using a subquery. Something like this:

```
SELECT
  tmax.cid,
  tmax.maxdate,
  table1.email,
  table2.status
FROM
  table2
  INNER JOIN table1
    ON table1.cid = table2.id

  INNER JOIN (

               SELECT
                 cid,
                 max(date) AS maxdate
               FROM
                 table1
               GROUP BY
                 cid
             ) AS tmax

    ON tmax.cid = table1.cid AND tmax.maxdate = table1.date;
```

The above query executed on your data set, will give this exact output (2 rows):

```
cid   maxdate             email       status
12345 2018-02-13 09:41:43 a@gmail.com 1
45678 2018-02-02 10:14:42 n@gmail.com 1
```

which means, in English: "For each id in table2, bring its status, and bring the line in table1 for the corresponding cid, and whose date is the max date for same cid within table1."

Because I used `INNER JOIN`s, the records in table1 that mention a `cid` that does not exist in table2, are discarded.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, I have to try that, however the id in this case is of same table, but I am looking for id from table2, so just wondering if I am reading the query correctly.

Comment: @vraviz It's the same. You can still join the whole thing with your Table2. What I meant is: in order to bring *the line* from Table1 that corresponds to the highest date for the specified id, you need to use a subquery joining on Table1 again.

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel, will definitely try this and update.

Comment: @Gabrial, so after quick test I see that this is listing all the users not the max date row alone. (equivalent to select * from table1) so this would not be helpful if i join it with table2 result would be same I believe.

Comment: Can someone else pour some more light on this please? tried few sub query options but none have been fruitful to give me the result i am looking for ;(

Comment: @vraviz I'm not sure you invested enough time in trying this direction. I like to see SO as a peer-learning platform where one may find ideas and directions to pursue their own research and learning, rather than a copy-paste engine. I will paste you the solution tomorrow if I find the time — but what I wrote (as pseudo-code) is the correct direction to look at, if you're able to spend some time investigating ;-)

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, apology if I have missed in taking suggested directions, have tried few options maybe not sure if i did on same lines. Most of the times either I get all the rows or it keeps repeating the same values as in example output. Frankly speaking I am not well versed so while i was learning got stuck with this problem not letting me proceed further hence pinged again. Will try some more options after reading the suggestions again.

Comment: @vraviz I've edited my response. You can now copy-paste... Hope this fits for an accepted answer now :-)

Comment: perfect, I am quite embarrassed as well, but i did not make note of earlier query and still puzzled where did i go wrong. I am not saying I had same new query with me, however i think i missed playing with id, cid part which you have put very nicely which if i remember correctly yesterday i did not dig much towards. And of course i must have not put in effort with respect to Inner joins in right way as well.

Comment: @vraviz I didn't mean to be rude or patronizing — sorry if I sounded so :-) I only meant that we never learn as good and sustainably as when we fail-and-retry over a hint to solution :) Glad I could help

Answer (score -1):

You could write the query like this (add an order desc on u.date):

```
SELECT c.id 'table 2 Id', DATE_FORMAT(MAX(u.date),'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') 'Date', u.email 'User'
FROM table2 c
LEFT JOIN table1 u ON u.cId = c.id
WHERE c.status = 1 
GROUP BY c.id 
ORDER BY c.id, u.date DESC;
```